# How can I choose which Swift Compiler version I want to use in Nativescript?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm having an issue as the library `nativescript-toast` is using a version of iOS Toaster in Swift 3 and not in v4.
And this is making my build failed when I run `tns run ios`.

After reading some posts I found the solution which is to open xcode, go to Build Settings and for `Toaster` target choose Swift 3 in `Swift Language Version`,
In this way I can build my app using xCode... but this is a problem also, as It's not reflecting the changes I'm doing in real time in VS Code, and the changes that I'm doing in xCode is only impacting iOS and not Android as I'm in platform/ios folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Toaster'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Credits to nStudio, based on [nativescript-camera-plus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus/blob/master/src/platforms/ios/Podfile) plugin

Comment: Ahh ok! I found out that this need to be added to the podfile.. great! I'll try it and get back!